# Passing a list of derived classes to a function expecting a list of base classes in C++

Tags: c++, list, inheritance, vector, shared-ptr

I have the following classes

```
class Parent {
  virtual void doStuff() = 0;
};

class Child : public Parent {
  void doStuff() {
    // Some computation here
  }
};
```

And I have a function with the following signature.

```
void computeStuff(std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Parent> >);
```

Provided I can refactor my code (including the function signature), **what is the best way to pass the function `computeStuff` a list of pointers to `Child` objects?**

Essentially, I would like the following snippet of code to compile and run

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Child> > listOfChilds = getList();
computeStuff(listOfChilds);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "best" way would be to have the function take a pair of iterators:

```
template <typename ForwardIterator>
void computeStuff(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last) {
    /* ... */
}
```

You can call this function as:

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Child> > listOfChilds = getList();
computeStuff(listOfChilds.begin(), listOfChilds.end());
```

There are a lot of advantages to taking a pair of iterators instead of a container, but the two big ones here are that

- the `computeStuff` function can take a range from any type of container, not just a `std::vector`, and
- the range just has to contain objects that are convertible to the type that you want to use (e.g. `boost::shared_ptr<Parent>`), it doesn't actually have to contain objects of that specific type.